# When i click the dropdownlist its not listing in a model

Tags: drop-down-menu, model

Not displaying the dropdownlist

listing dropdown in a model not listing the dropdown. it is pointing to close button. it is not showing the list details. Its just in a div , the dropdown is not displaying the value [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ueli0.png)